# passing instance variables into external scriptlets

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, integration-testing, factory-bot

In the interests of code reuse I am constructing an external library of rspec scriptlets(defined here as a method wrapping an it block) (like so:)

```
module MyTestSuite
  module Scriptlets
    module Navigation

       def it_will_demo_concept_of_scriptlets
         it "will demo concepts of scriptlets" do
               ...
         end
       end

       def it_will_navigate_to_object(object)
         it "will navigate to object" do
                .... 
                ....actions and expectations go here
                ....
                ....
         end
       end
    end
   end
end
```

This then gets imported like so:

```
include MyTestSuite::Scriptlets::Navigation

feature "my tests" do

    before(:each) do
       @object = create(:my_object)
    end

    describe "my tests" do
       it_will_demo_concept_of_scriptlets
       it_will_navigate_to_object(@object.some_param)
    end
end
```

if the navigate scriptlet is removed, everything runs fine, however if it is instated, the following error message is produced:

`undefined method 'some_param' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

This seems to suggest that the body of the describe block is parsed before the before condition? What is going on? How do I work around this?

EDIT:

As suggested by Steve below, I have attempted to rewire everything through shared_examples.

This led to the spec executing as a feature/request level spec with the webpage under test refreshing between every example, rather then the integration level spec I am shooting for.

The code looked identical to the sample above, except every `def` was replaced with a `shared_example`, and the "method" (example) names were stringified and followed by `do`, and then called appropriately.

If anyone knows of a `shared_examples` based workaround for the problem, that would also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@object` is nil when you call `it_will_navigate_to_object(@object.some_param)` because it is not running in the same context as the `before` block in which you initialize it.

Roughly speaking RSpec allows you to share instance variables by generating a class for your example groups (e.g. your `feature` block) and running the blocks passed into `before` and `it` in the context of a new instance of that class for each code example. What is going wrong here is that the call to `it_will_navigate_to_object(@object.some_param)` is run in the context of class (so `self` is the class rather than the instance of that class).

It might be worth taking a look at shared examples to achieve what you are trying to do. See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/example-groups/shared-examples. In particular the section on 'Providing context to a shared group using a block'.

Comment: thank you that's kind of cool! one more question, how would I go about doing something like so using this approach:

def it_will_click(button)
        self.send(:"it_will_click_#{button.downcase}")
      end

      private

      def it_will_click_done
        it "clicks Done" do
          click_on "Done"
        end
      end

      def it_will_click_cancel
        it "clicks Cancel" do
          click_on "Cancel"
        end
      end